# Netlogo: How to command to show me the exact value of a plot?

Tags: netlogo

Hi want to do a simple thing, but do not know how. I want to check if my curve touches 0 at any point, or better I want to know the value of the curve at the 1000 mark (this mark is 1000 ticks). But I do not know what to type in the command center. I know that it is the name of my variable, but I can not find the right code.

Can somebody please help me?

[forest plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exLwg.png)

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but you could do `export-plot` (or Export -> Plot on the File menu) and inspect the resulting data file in another application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible.

However, instead, when you plot, you plot some value, in your code, why don't you check if that value is ever 0, or `if ticks = 1000 [show value]`

Comment: "I don't think this is possible." — agree, there is nothing in the NetLogo language that lets you inspect already-plotted data.

Comment: @SethTisue  It would be really nice to get a list of points as say
`plot-pen-values "plotname" "penname"`

Comment: Maybe someone will build this as an extension? I wouldn't give it a high chance of becoming a priority for the core language.